# Pass HttpPostedFileBase object in asp.net Identity action method and validating with face api

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity

Hello guys i try to implement a registration functionality using asp.net identity.

One of my required properties is the new user's photo  which  i pass as an argument in a  action method where finally  i call `faceServiceClient.DetectAsync()` method of azure face api.

I grab the photo using a `<input type='file'>` in my view 
and then in account controller of identity in register action method i use a `HttpPostedFileBase object` to read it.

The problem is that `faceServiceClient.DetectAsync()` needs as first argument a stream object or a string(imagePath) but in my case i cant figure it out how i can give a stream object or the image path

`HttpPostedFileBase` doesn't retrieve the image path but to get the image i need this type of object.

And then even if i try to pass `httpPostedFilebase object.InputStream` as argument i get null by break pointing the `await faceServiceClient.DetectAsync` command line

To be specific

**Account Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register([Bind(Exclude = "UserPhoto")]RegisterViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase userPhoto)
    {
        if ((userPhoto==null) || (userPhoto.ContentLength <= 0))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("error", @"Please Select a profile picture");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
          var faceApiresult = await new FaceRecognitionController().GetDetectedFaces(userPhoto);

          if (!faceApiresult)
          {
               ModelState.AddModelError("error", @"Your picture does not include your face");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }



            var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    UName = model.Username,
                    UserPhoto = model.UserPhoto
                };

                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");


                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);

        }


        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and my  **FaceRecognitionController**

```
public class FaceRecognitionController : Controller
{

    private static string ServiceKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FaceServiceKey"];
    private static string EndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FaceServiceEndPoint"];

            [HttpGet]
            public  async Task<dynamic> GetDetectedFaces(HttpPostedFile userPhoto)
            {
              var photo = new byte[userPhoto.ContentLength];

              if (userPhoto.ContentLength == 0) return false;
                try
                {
                    // Create Instance of Service Client by passing Servicekey as parameter in constructor 
                    var faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient(ServiceKey);
                    var faces = await faceServiceClient.DetectAsync(userPhoto.InputStream, true, true, new FaceAttributeType[] { FaceAttributeType.Gender, FaceAttributeType.Age, FaceAttributeType.Smile, FaceAttributeType.Glasses });
                    //check if find any faces
                    var results = faces.Length;


                    return results != 0;
                }
                catch (FaceAPIException)
                {
                    //do exception work
                }

                return false;
            }

           }
         }
```

As you can see i just check if validation api find any face and just return true to complete the registration

any thoughts on how i can overcome this??

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more searching i found this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads

in which i read that i can use this line of code

```
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
```

and get the temp file path .So after that i successfully  added it  as a parameter to the action method and then in `faceServiceClient.DetectAsync`
and use tis path as first argument and worked